# Find Taylor's series

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find Taylor's series around 0 and find the radius of convergence:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

I understand that you probably need to use Taylor's series for arcsin, but I can't find the way.

Comment: your de4nominator is $ (1-x^{2})^{3/2} $ use binomial theorem expansion and you get it , remember that your function will have only powers of $ x^{2n}$ since your function is even

Comment: $f(x)=(1-x^2)^{-\frac 32}$

Comment: From analysis in one complex variable we get the radius of convergence as the distance to closest pole. Poles are at $x=\pm 1$, so radius should be $1$. The series converges for all complex $x$ inside the unit disc, and the special case along the real line: $-1<x<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just notice that...

$$f(x)=(1-x^2)^{-3/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-3/2}n(-x^2)^n=1+\frac32x^2+\frac{15}8x^4+\dots$$

[Generalized binomial expansion theroem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem).

For the radius of convergence, notice that

$$\left|\frac{\binom{-3/2}{n+1}(-x^2)^{n+1}}{\binom{-3/2}n(-x^2)^n}\right|=\frac{2n+1}{2n}x^2\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow x^2<1$$

So $-1<x<1$ is the open interval of convergence.